# Swift: Camera wont reopen after closing/ using it

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Within my app I can take a picture

I have a button to access the camera (with all the permission and all) 
it works, I can take a picture or close it if i wanted to

but after doing either of the activity 
the camera button wont open the camera again
I have to exit the view controller and go back again for it to work

```
@IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) && !pickedImage {
            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            pickedImage = true
        }
    }
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

After taking a picture there is a `UIImageView` for it to display taken picture.

I need to two things 
1. In the camera access i can also select pictures from the gallery and make it display on the UIImageView
2. To have the camera button reopen the camera after using it

Comment: I think your boolen is not properly manage `!pickedImage`

Comment: put break point and check boolean

Comment: @JaydeepVyas I changed the boolean to false 
`pickedImage = false` its okay now. Thanks... selecting an image in the gallery is next now

Comment: imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum for gallary

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/sourcetype for more description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To select pictures from gallery, you will have to set `sourceType` as `.photoLibrary` .
2. I think your `pickedImage` variable is never set to `false`, hence the second time, it doesn't get inside that if condition.

Comment: this should be comment